# Django database admin cannot login

Tags: django, django-templates, pyhook

I've deploy a django to my own VPS, My DB is SQLite3, also I've set to **777**. on homepage the data from database retrieve well,but I don't know why I can't login as admin

[image]

here is my settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'NAME' : '/var/www/html/mysite.com/db.sqlite3'
    }
}
```

Also I've try to **erroring** the db path but the homepage still working fine (it's should error cause I've renamed my db)

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Please show the full traceback (as text, not an image).

Answer (score 0):

You're having a cache problem I think, be sure your migrations are fine and then press Command+Option+R if you are on Mac or Ctrl + F5 if you are on Windows machine when opening the port or probably delete all the migrations except the **init** file and start from scratch.